# Cómo recargar tabla de material con información nueva en Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript

Estoy usando Angular 7 y quiero que cuando cambio el nombre de la persona que busco, la tabla actualice la información, pero no está funcionando:

En el componente principal tengo esto:

```
<div fxLayaout= "row">
  <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center" fxFlex="50"     fxLayoutGap="5px">
  </div>
<div fxLayout="row"  fxFlex fxLayoutAlign="end center">
  <employee-autocomplete
    [control]="name"
  ></employee-autocomplete>
  <button mat-mini-fab aria-label="Buscar historial de empleado" (click)="actionSearch()">
    <mat-icon>search</mat-icon>
  </button>
</div>
</div>
<app-employee-historic-list
  *ngIf="show == true"
  [arrayHistory]="historic"
></app-employee-historic-list>
```

actionSearch lo que hace es:

```
actionSearch() {
    this.show = false;
    this.service
  .getHistoryByUsername(this.name.value)
  .pipe(take(1))
  .subscribe((history) => {
     this.historic = history;
   });
   this.show = true;
```

Luego en la lista component, en el ts tengo esto:

```
export class EmployeeHistoricListComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @Input() arrayHistory: Historic[];
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Historic>;
  @ViewChild(MatTable) table : MatTable 
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  displayedColumns: string[] = [
    'ID',
    'Asignado a',
    'Tipo',
    'Marca',
    'Oficina',
    'Fecha de asignación',
    'Realizado por'
  ];
  constructor() {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  console.log(this.arrayHistory)
  this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.arrayHistory);
  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }
  applyFilter(event: Event) {
    const filterValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
  }
}
```

Entonces, cuando en el componente padre busco un empleado, lo que quiero lograr es que se reinicié o recargue el componente hijo con la data. Por qué no funciona así?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en la función `actionSearch()`, en esta línea  `this.historic = history;`. El componente hijo está enlazado con el arreglo al que hace referencia la variable `historic` y ese arreglo es el que debe modificarse para que los datos se actualicen en el hijo.

En lugar de: `this.historic = history;` se debe hacer lo siguiente:

```
.subscribe((history) => {
     // una forma de limpiar el arreglo historic
     this.historic.splice(0,this.historic.length);

     //this.historic = history; 

     // insertar los nuevos en elementos en el arreglo this.historic
     // usando el mismo arreglo al que hace referencia el elemento hijo
     history.forEach(h => this.historic.push(h));
   });
```